# Pushing Laravel App to heroku fails - valid cache path error

Tags: php, git, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I'm trying to push a test Laravel application to Heroku but whenever I try to do so I get an error and the deployment stops. This is whats displayed when I do a deploy:

```
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
remote:        > php artisan optimize
remote:        
remote:                                              
remote:          [InvalidArgumentException]          
remote:          Please provide a valid cache path.  
remote:                                              
remote:        
remote:        Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

What's the issue here? The storage/framework folder has all the needed folders and they're included in the repository. So whats wrong here?

Comment: Try to check the permission on your folders. most folders should be normal "755" and files, "644"
Laravel requires some folders to be writable for the web server user. You can use this command on *nix based OSs.

`sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache`
`sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: I'll check I think the folders are 777 in this case - I'll give it a shot

Comment: Nope doesnt work - still gives the same error.

Comment: Please triple check and confirm that the following folders are made: `storage/framework` and inside the framework folders the following 3: `sessions` , `views`, `cache`

Comment: and try the following artisan commands: `php artisan cache:clear`, 
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Where do I do these commands - if I run php artisan optimize on my local system it works fine but when I push it to heroku - I get this error as above...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144736/discussion-between-ali-and-jesse-de-gans).

Answer (score 0):

Just check the gitignore file if has /storage/*.key or /storage/* remove it and again run commit and push.